# Clutchless manual transmission

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission

I have an Isuzu truck which has just had the clutch replaced.  It has a clutchless manual transmission which has not been working since the replacement of the clutch.  There is a light in the dash hsa/cfs which is on and I can't switch it off, can you offer any help?

Comment: Unless you did the work yourself, take it back to your mechanic and have them fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Your vehicle has a standard clutch. The gear shifting is done by electronic controls and an ECU. You need to scan the transmission components for any faults, and perhaps to re-set the system if the battery was disconnected, as it should have been, during the replacement of the clutch. If the replacement was done for you then returning it to the mechanic would be your first option.